# ¿como hacer un bucle for con array bi dimensional en PHP?

Tags: php

tengo 2 variables que vienen por método get

```
 if(isset($_GET['p'])){
  $_SESSION['producto']['id'] = $_GET['p']; 
  }

 if(isset($_GET['c'])){
 $_SESSION['producto']['can'] = $_GET['c']; 
 }
```

con eso necesito hacer un bucle foreach que recorra el array bi dimensional y después hacer una consulta query y poner los datos de la consulta con while

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['producto']); $i+=2 ){

 $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
 id='.$_SESSION['producto']['id'].''); //no pongo mas para no aburrir
```

la cosa esque cone so me arroja el resultado bien pero si sigo dando click en añadir carrito ya no se ejecuta el codigo  no s esi ya no recorre el bucle solo se cambia de informacion a medida que doy click si tengo 1 y vuelvo a dar click en ves de aumentar otra linea a ese 1 la cambia por 2 y nada más

Answer (score 0):

No llego a entender del todo el problema completo, ya que dices que quiere que se recorra todo el array, pero el bucle for lo incrementas de 2 en 2. Pero lo que sí puedo ver es que no usas bien el bucle for. El bucle for no puede incrementar así: `i+=2`.

Si quieres que la variable i se incremente de uno en uno sería así:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['producto']); $i++ ){
```

Pero si realmente querías que incremente de 2 en 2, la sentencia que muestras también es incorrecta. Se debe hacer así:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['producto']); $i+2 ){
```

Comment: si le pongo i+=2 logro que me salga todo en la misma linea si le pongo como dices i+2 no sale nada....si le pongo i++ me sale 2 lineas con la informacion peor loque quiero es que cada vez que de click en añadir salga la informacion en una linea si doy 3 veces serian 3 lineas asi peor ahora me sale 1 y si doy click en otro producto solo cambia esa linea por otra peor no aumenta